# What is a word or phrase for "The point in time when the work pays off and it takes care of itself from here"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am writing a presentation on [BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) and the [Cucumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucumber_(software)) software tool, and need a snappy title for one of the points I'm making: That if you put in the work and spend some time carefully parametrizing the step definition/implementation files, then there will become a point in time that you will no longer need to write any more step implementation files and the work will suddenly become very easy, and you can now throw together loads of BDD tests in no time at all.

I'm thinking of calling it **"The Parameterization Threshold"**, but "threshold" has connotations that it is something that you shouldn't cross. There must be a better word/words for this.

Another could be **"The Parameterization Return on Investment"**, but that doesn't capture that the ROI is very good, and happens at a certain point in time and that the effort you have put in is suddenly paying off and now you can do things with great ease.

Any suggestions?

*edit:* I was asked for an example sentence:

"It takes some time and effort to carefully parameterize the step files, however, once you reach the <word/phrase/idiom> then it's amazing. After this point, you can rapidly create more tests with ease"

Comment: Provide sentence using the term,

Comment: How about a 'sweet spot' in time?

Comment: @Xanne I've added an example sentence to the original question.

Comment: @LeonConrad That's good, I like how it is not financially inclined. However, I do think it implies that if you add more parameterization then you leave the "sweet spot", which is not the case. It is a line, not a spot. Once you cross it, more parameterization will not be a bad thing.

Comment: I think I would disagree with thresholds being something you shouldn't cross. To me, it's far more often used as a minimum standard which should be attained for something else to happen (which is exactly what you want to express). See [Lexico sense 2](https://www.lexico.com/definition/threshold).

Comment: would you like to call it "baseline"?

Comment: In other contexts this might be the 'break even' point

Comment: A threshold is also often a point where something significant happens as a result of crossing it.

Comment: I think your understanding of the connotations associated with “threshold” is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with critical point.

"Critical point is a wide term used in many branches of mathematics. When dealing with functions of a real variable, a critical point is a point in the domain of the function where the function is either not differentiable or the derivative is equal to zero."

Where the given point is at either the top of a peak or hill in the graph, or, at the bottom of a low or valley in the graph. Or, at a saddle point, where the graph changes from being a valley to being a hill - at a given point somewhere in between.

In applied mathematics, critical point refers to stuff like  the point at which the greenhouse effect becomes irreversible.

In nuclear physics, critical mass is about stuff like how much mass is required to sustain a nuclear reaction.

Another option is tipping point.

"The tipping point is the critical point in an evolving situation that leads to a new and irreversible development. The term is said to have originated in the field of epidemiology when an infectious disease reaches a point beyond any local ability to control it from spreading more widely."

There is also turning point, point of no return, and, I guess, so on.  Breaking point.  Point of inflection.

Answer (score 1):

- **It's all downhill from here.**

> All downhill from here
>
> 2. Increasingly easy (as if literally traveling downhill, as opposed to uphill).
>
> - *I'm sure I can finish the rest of the experiment on my own –
>   it's all downhill from here.*

[[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/all+downhill+from+here)]

But note that the 'downhill is a bad direction' metaphor shows in an equally valid contradictory meaning:

> 1. Steadily worsening.
>
> - *Once my parents open my report card and see how bad my grades are, it's all downhill from here.* [op cit]

.............

An unambiguous, but informal, alternative is **home free**:

> home free [Informal]
>
> having finished the worst or most difficult part of something
>
> - *If the refugees can make it as far as the United States, are they home free?*

[[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/home-free)]